# Register a touch event on Windows 10 (without a mouse click or actual touch)

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-10, tablet

I'm developing an application for windows 10 (PC device) that uses the capability of "tablet mode".

I want to register a touch event on a given x and y position (without a mouse click or actual touch).  What are the APIs for handling this kind of action in C#?

Comment: Can you clarify please: your platform (Win32 or UWP), do you want to create a touch event or to listen to it?

Comment: I update the question , it is a PC device @OlehNechytailo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simulate touch event in Windows there is a Win32 API for it.

[MSDN: InjectTouchInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802881(v=vs.85).aspx)

[NuGet: C# wrapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TCD.System.TouchInjection/)

You can simulate absolutely any combination of pointer input that Windows 10 is capable of, including pressure, contact area, pens, touch, mouse, multitouch, etc.

Sample code:

```
//usings:
using TCD.System.TouchInjection;
using static TCD.System.TouchInjection.TouchInjector;


// code:

InitializeTouchInjection();

var pointer = new PointerTouchInfo();

//We can add different additional touch data
pointer.TouchMasks = TouchMask.PRESSURE;
pointer.Pressure = 100;


//Pointer ID is for gesture tracking
pointer.PointerInfo.PointerId = 1;
pointer.PointerInfo.pointerType = PointerInputType.TOUCH;

pointer.PointerInfo.PtPixelLocation.X = 200;
pointer.PointerInfo.PtPixelLocation.Y = 200;

pointer.PointerInfo.PointerFlags = PointerFlags.INRANGE | PointerFlags.INCONTACT | PointerFlags.DOWN;

InjectTouchInput(1, new[] { pointer });

//Hold touch for some time
Thread.Sleep(100);

pointer.PointerInfo.PointerFlags = PointerFlags.UPDATE;

InjectTouchInput(1, new []{ pointer });
```

Comment: In case the 3rd party component becomes inaccessible, this post will seize to be useful. Please provide an answer that doesn't rely on 3rd party components. Besides, the touch injection API is available starting with Windows 8. This is an important detail, since there are still supported versions of Windows (Vista, 7), where this is not a solution.